# CentOS 6.9, Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: 10gen, how to?

Tags: centos, repository

I just started having this issue today. Any ideas?

```
[root@centos-4gb-nyc2-01 ~]# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Setting up Upgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                         |  15 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * remi-php72: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * rpmforge: repoforge.spinellicreations.com
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Downloaded more than max size for https://www.mongodb.com/: 125776 > 102400
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: 10gen. Please verify its path and try again
[root@centos-4gb-nyc2-01 ~]#
```

Comment: What happened when you looked at the content of that URL?

Comment: redirect to the homepage

Comment: That suggests that the URL of the repository in its file is wrong. Did they happen to rearrange their website? Have you checked to make sure you have installed a current version of the repo file?

Comment: I'm trying to remove that repo.. but I can't seem to find it.. weird.

Comment: Looks like there is no more `10gen` but they changed the name to `mongodb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Package was corrupted so the actual size of the package differ form the one available in repodata. As the actual size of package and the one in repodata differs yum fail to download the package.

Try to delete and again download the problematic package in the local repository.
Regenerate repodata for local repository:

# createrepo --update /path/to/rpms

On the Client System clear the yum cache and again try to install the package:

# yum clean all

# yum -y install

In your case downloads-distro.mongodb.org url repo meta is corrupted, you need to recreate it.

Hope this will help.